# How to implement a promise in java which changes the output type

Tags: java, promise

I'm trying to implement a simple promise system in java. I'm doing it for special purpose so please don't recommend any libraries.

I have a problem when I try to implement a `thenApply()` method which takes a Function as parameter, similar to what [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) has and therefore returns a promise with another type.

The promise interface:

```
public interface Promise<T> {
    Promise<T> then(Consumer<T> handler);

    <U> Promise<U> thenApply(Function<T, U> handler);
}
```

My implementation so far:

```
public class PromiseImpl<T> implements Promise<T> {

    private List<Consumer<T>> resultHandlers = new ArrayList<>();

    public PromiseImpl(CompletableFuture<T> future) {
        future.thenAccept(this::doWork);
    }

    @Override
    public Promise<T> then(Consumer<T> handler) {
        resultHandlers.add(handler);
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public <U> Promise<U> thenApply(Function<T, U> handler) {
        // How to implement here??? I don't have the result yet
        handler.apply(?);
    }

    private void onResult(T result) {
        for (Consumer<T> handler : resultHandlers) {
            handler.accept(result);
        }
    }

    private Object doWork(T result) {
        onResult(result);
        return null;
    }
}
```

The problem is that I don't know the result of my initial future in the `thenApply()` method, so I cannot call my handler. Also, I don't want to call `future.get()` because this method is blocking.

How could I make this work?

Comment: You've not specified what you want `thenApply` to actually do...

Comment: @Michael same as `then` method but with another return type

Comment: How do you plan on getting the return value? `Promise` has no method to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The real problem is in the design of your `Promise` type. It is holding a set of callbacks, all of which are to be invoked on completion. This is a fundamental problem (limiting generic functionality around the return type of `thenApply`'s function). This can be resolved by changing your `Promise` implementation to return a `new` promise whenever a handler is registered, instead of returning `this`, such that each promise object will have its own handler to invoke.

In addition to solving this, it's a better design for functional-style programming, as you can make your `Promise` objects immutable.

I would change the interface to be:

```
interface Promise<T> {
    <U> Promise<U> thenApply(Function<T, U> handler);
    Promise<Void> thenAccept(Consumer<T> consumer);
}
```

The "chaining" of callbacks can then be done around the future objects to which chained `Promise` instances have references. So the implementation can look like:

```
class PromiseImpl<T> implements Promise<T> {

    private CompletableFuture<T> future;

    public PromiseImpl(CompletableFuture<T> future) {
        this.future = future;
    }

    @Override
    public <U> Promise<U> thenApply(Function<T, U> function) {
        return new PromiseImpl<>(this.future.thenApply(function));
    }

    @Override
    public Promise<Void> thenAccept(Consumer<T> consumer) {
        return new PromiseImpl<>(this.future.thenAccept(consumer));
    }

    private void onResult(T result) {
        this.future.complete(result);
    }

    private Object doWork(T result) {
        onResult(result);
        return null;
    }
}
```

And using that can be as simple as:

```
Promise<String> stringPromise = new PromiseImpl<>(new CompletableFuture<String>());
Promise<Long> longPromise = stringPromise.thenApply(str -> Long.valueOf(str.length()));
Promise<Void> voidPromise = stringPromise.thenAccept(str -> System.out.println(str));
```

**EDIT:**

Regarding [Michael's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/89399395?noredirect=1) about retrieving the value: that was not added as it wasn't in the original `Promise` API. But it's easy enough to add:

```
T get(); //To the interface
```

And implemented with:

```
public T get() {
    //try-catch 
    return this.future.get();
}
```

**Note:** this is starting to look more and more like a duplication of `CompletableFuture`, which raises the question of why do this at all. But assuming there will be additional `Promise`-like methods in this interface, the method would be wrapping the future API.

---

If you need to use the same `Promise` object with a list of call backs, then you have no choice but to parameterize the `Promise` interface with both `Function` concrete type parameters:

```
public interface Promise<T, U>
```

And `U` wouldn't be able to be a method generic parameter on `then` or `thenApply`.

Comment: But should `thenAccept` return a `Promise<Void>`? What can I realistically do with a `Promise<Void>`? Why not just `void`?

Comment: @Michael I've edited for "how to retrieve a value", but that's essentially about using the future instance. `Promise<Void>` would not be useful unless the `Promise` interface is enriched with more methods, such as for checking the status, even if there's no value to be returned (so it would be similar to `CompletableFuture<Void>`. I assumed the version of the interface in the question was simplified. Otherwise, I really don't see why one wouldn't just use the `CompletableFuture`.

Comment: @ErnestKiwele Consider that I'm not on Java 8 which means I cannot use `CompletableFuture`. I just used the `CompletableFuture` as a simple method to show that there is some kind of delayed action. My fault, I should have mentioned that in the question.

Comment: @flash Absolutely, you could have many good reasons to do this, not arguing that. But then again, before Java8, we have a poorer `Future` interface, with `FutureTask<V>` implementing it. All I'm saying is that we should assume you have good reasons to implement this... :-)

Comment: @ErnestKiwele Sorry, not my best day today. I'm still stuck. How would the implementation change with `FutureTask`? It does have a `get` method but that would block the `thenApply` method, right?

Comment: @flash Well, I suppose I caused that confusion... I only mentioned the `Future` interface in the context of your hypothetical case of users not being on java 8. It's much poorer than `CompletableFuture` and it wouldn't make sense to switch to it. With that said, I hope there are reasons that got you to implement this wrapper around completablefuture...

Comment: Does it support multiple thenApply calls? such: promise.thenApply(r -> r).thenApply(t -> t);

Comment: @sharonooo Yes, `.thenApply` calls can be chained.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep the rest of your class the same and just implement the `thenApply` method, you have to make a new `CompletableFuture` since that's the only way you currently have to construct a new `Promise`:

```
@Override
public <U> Promise<U> thenApply(Function<T, U> handler) {
    CompletableFuture<U> downstream = new CompletableFuture<>();
    this.then(t -> downstream.complete(handler.apply(t)));
    return new PromiseImpl<>(downstream);
}
```

If you can add a private no-argument constructor for `PromiseImpl`, you can avoid making a new `CompletableFuture`:

```
@Override
public <U> Promise<U> thenApply(Function<T, U> handler) {
    PromiseImpl result = new PromiseImpl();
    this.then(t -> result.doWork(handler.apply(t)));
    return result;
}
```

But really what you should do if you want to implement your own API on top of `CompletableFuture` is use the decorator pattern and wrap a `CompletableFuture` instance as a private variable in `PromiseImpl`.

Answer (score 0):

You can return some anonymous class that extends your PromiseImpl and overrides onResult so handlers accept the result of applying mapper function. Do not forget to call the parent onResult so parent handlers will be called.

Comment: I don't think this solution works, because the types might not be compatible. Consider `String`and `Integer` as types. Please provide a code sample if you think I'm wrong.